# Query client's timezone with Google AppEngine XMPP library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp

**Context**
I have a jabber bot implemented in Python on Google AppEngine and their xmpp library.
The bot forwards posts from a social network and I'd like post timestamps are in client's timezone.

**Question**
Is it possible (and how) to query client for their local timezone so my bot can do respective adjustments? *Again, the bot is based on appengine's xmpp python library.*

**Alternatives**
Of course, it can ask clients to specify their timezone explicitly on setup, store that value somewhere and use it later. But I'd prefer my bot extracts this information automatically, without human involvement.

**Respective documentation**
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/

Comment: In case you need to see the code of the bot, here it is: https://github.com/ysoldak/plusxmpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is not possible, although [XMPP has the ability to query for time zone](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0202.html) Google App Engine doesn't allow to send raw stanzas.
There is an [issue about it](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2331) in acknowledged mode but don't bet on seeing it anytime soon.